# configure tls for traefik in kubernetes got Incomplete Certificate Chain Warning

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, certificate, traefik

I configure ingressRoute with tls:secretName,

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: test-ir
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`test.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: test-app
      port: 8080
  tls:
    secretName: traefik-tls-secret
```

and configure secret with full certificate chain.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 encoded server certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 encoded intermediate certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 encoded trusted CA certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But when I request it in chrome, the browser warn me that the certificate chain is not complete. So my question is how to configure full certificate chain in traefik?

Comment: You can configure a full certificate chain in traefik by using PEM file as is both for the key/cert configurations. [More infos](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-make-traefik-include-the-full-ca-chain/5423)

Comment: so I should put certs and key in one PEM file, and then create secret with it like:
kubectl create secret tls test-chain-secret --cert=ca.pem
right?

Answer (score 0):

The process I follow to use an externally-provided SSL certificate chain  (i.e with root/intermediary certs included) in traefik is as follows:

If not already supplied as a full PEM, start by combining the separate server certificate and intermediaries into one file:

```
cat server.crt intermediate.crt root.crt > cert-chain.pem
```

Generate a secret containing the full certificate chain and private key - note the secret must be in the same namespace as the `IngressRoute`:

```
kubectl create secret generic example-cert-secret --namespace apps --from-file=tls.crt=cert-chain.pem --from-file=tls.key=server.key
```

Finally add this secret to the `IngressRoute`:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: apps
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`example.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: my-app
      port: 8080
  tls:
    secretName: example-cert-secret
```

You can then verify that the cert is being served correctly with:

```
curl -vI https://example.com
```